# How can I find the integers $x,y$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

$$ax+by=c$$
$$ax^2+by^2=d$$
where $ab\neq 0$ and $x,y$ are coprime?

Comment: Well, the second implies that $abx^2+(by)^2=bd\implies abx^2+(c-ax)^2=bd$ so you have a quadratic equation.

Comment: I agree. However, I will have to establish conditions to ensure that the discriminant is a perfect square and another one to make sure that the solutions are not rationals but integers, I wonder if it's the only method.

Comment: But those conditions are real...not artifacts of the method.  One way or another you are going to have to grapple with them.  The discriminant is pretty ugly...removing a stray factor of $4$ I get $\Delta=a^2c^2-c^2ab-c^2a+ab^2d+abd$  which doesn't look promising, though anything is possible.  I would check that discriminant, by the way.  I did it very hastily and it could easily be wrong.

Comment: I appreciate your input @Lulu.

Comment: I just tried something different:

Comment: I just tried something different: $$a=\frac{  dy-c}{y-x}$$ $$b=\frac{c-dx}{y-x}$$ We set $$y=x+e$$ Then $$x=\frac{c-be}{d}$$ $$y=\frac{c-be}{d}+e$$. I just need to pick my $e$ such that $x$ is an integer. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Well...just looking at the bottom lines, if we let $c=be$ then you get $x=0, y=e$ independent of $a,d$ which seems wrong.

Comment: I suggest working a number of examples; including cases where there are no integer solutions for $x,y$.  Perhaps some useful pattern emerges.

Comment: When $x=0$ That yields the degenerate cases where $y=\pm 1$

Comment: Instead of solving for (real) roots (or trying it) I'd propose to start with looking $\pmod a$,$\pmod b$ and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this by talking the first equation and solving for y. Then substituting y in the second equation, as so:

$$ax+by=c$$

$$ax-c=-by$$

$$(ax-c)/(-b)=y$$

Now substitute into second equation:

$$ax^{2}+\frac{b\left(ax-c\right)^{2}}{b^{2}}=d$$

Expand:

$$ax^{2}+\frac{a^{2}x^{2}-2acx+c^{2}}{b}=d$$

Simplify:

$$\frac{bax^{2}}{b}+\frac{a^{2}x^{2}-2acx+c^{2}}{b}=d$$

$$\frac{bax^{2}+a^{2}x^{2}-2acx+c^{2}}{b}=d$$

Subtract d from both sides:

$$\frac{bax^{2}+a^{2}x^{2}-2acx+c^{2}-bd}{b}=0$$

Simplify more...

$$\frac{\left(a^{2}+ba\right)}{b}x^{2}-\frac{2ac}{b}x+\frac{\left(c^{2}-bd\right)}{b}=0$$

This is just a quadratic. You can solve it with the quadratic equation:

$$x=\frac{-g+\sqrt{g^{2}-4fh}}{2f}$$

And

$$x=\frac{-g-\sqrt{g^{2}-4fh}}{2f}$$

Where $$f=\frac{\left(a^{2}+ba\right)}{b}$$

$$g=-\frac{2ac}{b}$$

$$h=\frac{\left(c^{2}-bd\right)}{b}$$

Try it out: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dw9xe3ppxe

Comment: Where exactly did you get the f and the g. Please specify,

Comment: @Max0815 f is the coefficient of x^2, g is the coefficient of x, and h is the constant. Related to a, b, and c respectively in the quadratic formula.

Comment: We are asked to find integer solutions, not find real roots...

Comment: @zwim This will find the solutions to the system. Whether they are integers is dependent on a, b, c, and d. This can be used to determine whether they are or are not integers.

Answer (score -1):

[Easiest Possible solution. Its a simple solution using trignometry. I use this to solve many problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW6Tn.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to mathematics SE. Have a look at mathjax. It will help you write equation.

Comment: I doubt that would yield integer solutions.

Comment: Due to constant K, ksinx can be an integer

Answer (score -3):

Above simultaneous equation shown below:

$ax^2+by^2=d$

$ax+by=c$

Taking, $(a,b,c,d)=(4,5,22,56)$ we get:

$(x,y)=(3,2)$ & $(x,y)=(17/9,26/9)$